# Why are coordinate systems used in General Relativity if it is a background independent theory?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, covariance

I am studying topological manifolds as a prerequisite to studying General Relativity and although this question is premature since I have not yet begun the latter it is bothering me.

From basic physics I always heard that General Relativity is background independent.  Is this the same thing as saying it can be done without coordinate systems or just that it must be done with a coordinate system but the one you use doesn't really matter?

Comment: I mean, consider the statement: "this morning my little kid's height reached 3 feet". That is a _highly_ coordinate-dependent statement which depends on a notion of time, a definition of a height unit, a definition of where the zero of height is, and a definition for which direction you measure height in. Every actual concrete statement you make about the world uses coordinates. Making everything coordinate-free is a fun diversion for mathematicians, but not useful if you actually want to describe specific, real things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much the latter: coordinates are the tools we use to describe what is going on: there are no coordinates in nature and it does not really matter which coordinate system we use, so long as it's 'good': it should provide a suitably differentiable 1-1 map of the manifold (or an open subset of the manifold) into $\mathbb{R}^4$, so that we can talk about what is going on.  Of course, in practice the choice of coordinates matters a lot, because you want to choose one that makes calculations practical: this is just the same thing as in other parts of physics: you don't really want to be working on a problem with spherical symmetry in cartesian coordinates, say.

Of course there are also things you can do in GR without using coordinates at all: only *some* (probably most!) calculations require coordinates.

However there is a slight caveat to this: the way manifolds are *defined* (at least to a physicist: mathematicians may have more abstract definitions) is by specifying that there are continuous 1-1 maps between open sets of the manifold and open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  These collections of maps are, in fact, coordinate systems for the manifold.  So you could argue that there are, inherently, coordinate systems.  But it does not matter *what the coordinate systems are*: you can choose any good set you like.